# How to understand the variance formula?

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-theory, probability-distributions

[image]

How is the variance of Bernoulli distribution derived from the variance definition?

Comment: use the alternative definition of variance: $\mathbf{E}X^2 - (\mathbf{E}X)^2$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PMF of the Bernoulli distribution is
$$
p(x)=p^x(1-p)^{1-x}\qquad;\qquad\text{for}\ x\in\{0,1\},
$$
and the $n$-moment of a discrete random variable is
$$
\text{E}[X^n]=\sum_{x\,\in\,\Omega} x^np(x).
$$
Let $X$ be a random variable that follows a Bernoulli distribution, then
\begin{align}
\text{E}[X]&=\sum_{x\in\{0,1\}} x\ p^x(1-p)^{1-x}\\
&=0\cdot p^0(1-p)^{1-0}+1\cdot p^1(1-p)^{1-1}\\
&=0+p\\
&=p
\end{align}
and
\begin{align}
\text{E}[X^2]&=\sum_{x\in\{0,1\}} x^2\ p^x(1-p)^{1-x}\\
&=0^2\cdot p^0(1-p)^{1-0}+1^2\cdot p^1(1-p)^{1-1}\\
&=0+p\\
&=p.
\end{align}
Thus
\begin{align}
\text{Var}[X]&=\text{E}[X^2]-\left(\text{E}[X]\right)^2\\
&=p-p^2\\
&=\color{blue}{p(1-p)},
\end{align}
or
\begin{align}
\text{Var}[X]&=\text{E}\left[\left(X-\text{E}[X]\right)^2\right]\\
&=\text{E}\left[\left(X-p\right)^2\right]\\
&=\sum_{x\in\{0,1\}} (x-p)^2\ p^x(1-p)^{1-x}\\
&=(0-p)^2\ p^0(1-p)^{1-0}+(1-p)^2\ p^1(1-p)^{1-1}\\
&=p^2(1-p)+p(1-p)^2\\
&=(1-p)(p^2+p(1-p)\\
&=\color{blue}{p(1-p)}.
\end{align}

Comment: Remember, support of the Bernoulli distribution is only two, i.e. $0$ and $1$.

Comment: Why does the variance above in my question has $E[X^2] - (E[X])^2$ at the end of the calculation? Why $2E[X]E[X]$ is canceled out?

Comment: @user122358 Wiki explanation is already obvious. Expectation only works for random variable, in the example $X$ and $E[X^n]$ is **a constant**. Then using property of expectation, we have $E[aX]=a\cdot E[X]$, where $a$ is a constant.

Comment: @user122358 from the third line Wiki explanation
\begin{align}
Var[X]&=E[X^2]-2E[X]\cdot E[X]+(E[X])^2\\
&=E[X^2]-2(E[X])^2+(E[X])^2\\
&=E[X^2]-(E[X])^2.
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

IF $X \sim$ Bernoulli($p$), then what's the distribution of $X^2$? Find it, then find its expectation, that'll be $\mathbf{E}X^2$, and you already have $(\mathbf{E}X)^2$.

EDIT: the way it's done in the example you gave, it seems that they defined a different rv: $W = (X- \mathbf{E}X)^2$, which takes values $(0-p)^2$ and $(1-p)^2$ with corresponding probabilities.

Comment: I am afraid that I am not really with you...

Comment: pls see the edit

Answer (score 0):

In a Bernoulli distribution, $E(X) = p$. Remember, the Bernoulli takes value $1$ with probability $p$ and $0$ with probability $1-p$, so the expectation of $X$ is $1\cdot p + 0\cdot (1-p) = p$. The expectation of any function of the Bernoulli is similarly $(E(g(x)) = g(1)\cdot p + g(0)\cdot(1-p)$ Thus
$$
\begin{align}
Var(X) &= E\left((X - E(X))^2\right)\\
&= \overbrace{\underbrace{(1-p)^2}_{g(1)}\cdot p}^\textrm{Bernoulli = 1; probability p} + \underbrace{\overbrace{(0-p)^2}^{g(0)}\cdot(1-p)}_{\textrm{Bernoulli = 0; probability (1-p)}}\\
\end{align}
$$
The rest follows what you brought in the question

Comment: What is it concatenated with $+$ sign? I am too new to this.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand your question. If you mean _why_ the + sign, remember what the definition of a Bernoulli expectation is (I brought it in the second and third sentence of the answer), it is the value of whatever when the Bernoulli is 1 times the probability of the Bernoulli being 1 **plus** the value of whatever when the Bernoulli is 0 times the probability of the Bernoulli being 0.